# Merge 3 SQL Server queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, recursive-query

I have the following [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b57ce8a69e7ecf21ea352e7f5f049b8a)

There are 3 queries used to eventually get id's of the `tbl_objectBase` table

The first one is pretty straight forward - a simple JOIN which is used to simply retrieve id's from `tbl_location` and `tbl_serviceC_place`

```
SELECT location.id, location.title
FROM tbl_location AS location 
INNER JOIN tbl_serviceC_place AS scPlace
    ON (location.id = scPlace.place_id)
WHERE scPlace.id = 7 /* entry point this id is the only one, static part */
```

The second query is used to traverse the hierarchy in both directions from `tbl_location`

```
/*
Hopefully, this is the right way to traverse the hierarchy in both directions
*/
WITH r AS 
(
   SELECT id, parent, title, 0 as iteration
   FROM tbl_location
   WHERE id = 5 /*(here I need to assign to every id from the first JOIN, dynamic part)*/
  
   UNION ALL

   SELECT tbl_location.id, tbl_location.parent, tbl_location.title, r.iteration + 1
   FROM r
      JOIN tbl_location
          ON r.parent = tbl_location.id
          WHERE r.iteration >= 0
          
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT tbl_location.id, tbl_location.parent, tbl_location.title, r.iteration - 1
   FROM r 
       JOIN tbl_location
       ON tbl_location.parent = r.id
       WHERE r.iteration <= 0
      
)

SELECT * FROM r
```

And finally, there's a simple select to retrieve id's from `tbl_objectBase`

```
SELECT id 
FROM tbl_objectBase 
WHERE location = 6 /* set location from every id from the recursive query, dynamic too */
```

My question is how to merge all these 3 queries together to get id's from `tbl_objectBase`?

Comment: I am confused with what you want. The 3 queries that you have posted in the question is in different order from the dbfiddle. Can you explain what do you want and what is the expected final result ?

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry, it's reversed order
My goal is to get ids from tbl_objectBase based on the ids that I got from the first join and recursive query

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I have understood the requirements, but I think this is what you want. These recursive queries can be thorny.

The first query of the recursive part is the "starting point", but no reason it can't return more than one row, so insert one query there (I have then simplified it a bit). Then just join your result at the end to the other table to merge the other query in.

```
WITH r AS 
(
   -- this is the starting point query
   SELECT location.id, parent, title, 0 as iteration
   FROM tbl_location as location
   INNER JOIN tbl_serviceC_place AS scPlace
      ON location.id = scPlace.place_id
   WHERE scPlace.id = 7
  
   UNION ALL

   SELECT tbl_location.id, tbl_location.parent, tbl_location.title, r.iteration + 1
   FROM r
      JOIN tbl_location
          ON r.parent = tbl_location.id
          WHERE r.iteration >= 0
          
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT tbl_location.id, tbl_location.parent, tbl_location.title, r.iteration - 1
   FROM r 
       JOIN tbl_location
       ON tbl_location.parent = r.id
       WHERE r.iteration <= 0
      
)

SELECT ob.id FROM r
INNER JOIN tbl_objectBase ob on r.id = ob.location -- this does the final select
```